# Android: one of many fragments to have action bar and others do not

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-theme

I'm wondering if there is a way to have the `ActionBar` in the theme of only one of the `Fragment`s of my `Activity` and the other `Fragment`s will go with the `Application`'s theme of no `ActionBar`?

In essence, how do I set a separate theme for one of my fragments such that it over-seeds the theme of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options

1. You could just hide the action bar using

   `getActivity().getActionBar().hide();`

Dont forget to use `getSupportActionBar()` if using support lib

2. The second option is to set a new theme for the fragment using Theme.NoActionBar

I think you want ContextThemeWrapper. In onCreateView of your fragment

You create a copy of your activity context wrapped in your theme.

```
Context themeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.myTheme);
```

then Create a copy of the existing LayoutInflater object, with the copy using to your theme wrapped context.

```
LayoutInflater inflaterCopy = inflater.cloneInContext(themeWrapper);
```

Then inflate your layout with the copied inflater because it has your wrapped context.

```
View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
```

Put this in onCreateView and use its layout inflater to copy